# get data from sql table to look like grids

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have the following code for retrieving the data from the sql table.
This code retrieves only the last record.
I want to show all the data in the table.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select auction_number, auction_title from Auctions", con);
            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                Label1.Text = (myReader["auction_number"].ToString());
                Label2.Text = (myReader["auction_title"].ToString());
            }
        }
```

I want to make the data look like in the following drawing.
[image]

Should I use tables?! Divs?! or is it possible with GridViews?

Comment: can you show me an example?

Comment: Use DataAdapter (not DataReader) and put into DataGridView.DataSource = dt.  See webpage https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx.  Use DataTable instead of DataSet.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad - you need a control that shows multiple "rows" (`DataGrid`, `Repeater`, etc.) and you need to bind it to your data source (you can use either the `DataReader` or a `DataSet`).  There are plenty of tutorials out there on either problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one approach with `asp:Repeater` combined with `<div>`

aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="edsList">  
<ItemTemplate>
<div>
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("auction_number") %>'></asp:Label>
 <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("auction_title") %>'></asp:Label>
 </div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

cs:

```
string query = "select auction_number, auction_title from Auctions";
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection))
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);

        Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current SQL selects two fields for each row in the table.

You could change your C# to display this as 3 pairs to a row like Barlet's answer.

OR you could change your SQL to return the data "shaped" like you want.  This is how to do it:

```
 select max(case when rn % 3 = 0 then auction_number else 0 end) as an1,
        max(case when rn % 3 = 0 then auction_title else '' end) as at1,
        max(case when rn % 3 = 1 then auction_number else 0 end) as an2,
        max(case when rn % 3 = 1 then auction_title else '' end) as at2,
        max(case when rn % 3 = 2 then auction_number else 0 end) as an3,
        max(case when rn % 3 = 2 then auction_title else '' end) as at3
 from (select auction_number, auction_title, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rn
       from Auctions) sub
 group by trunc(rn / 3)
```

Probably better to do it in C# -- but it can be done in SQL